# Cumulative sum after 64 in Python

Tags: python

The following is my data,

```
               count  
0               239  
1                47  
2                47  
3                47  
4                47  
5                47  
6                47  
7                47  
8                47  
9                47  
10               47  
11               48  
12               48  
13               48  
14               48  
15               48  
16               48  
17               48  
18               48  
19               48  
20               48  
21               48  
22               48  
23               48  
24               48  
25               48  
26               48  
27               48  
28               49  
29               50
```

I want to get the cumulative sum of the counter value once it reaches 64. For eg, if my data is as follows,

```
In [125]: x
Out[125]: 
array([ 57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  61.,
        61.,  62.,  62.,   1.,   1.,  11.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,
        16.,  22.,  22.,  22.,  27.,  28.])
```

My output should be,

```
array([ 57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  61.,
        61.,  62.,  62.,  65.,  65.,  75.,  80.,  80.,  80.,  80.,  80.,
        80.,  86.,  86.,  86.,  91.,  92.])
```

For the above mentioned example, the code i tried was as follows,

```
(np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=[0])<0).cumsum()*64 + x
```

This code seems to work well for the example.

But for my original data, I am getting the following,

```
Count
239
111
.
.
.
112
.
.
.
113
114
```

whereas my expected output is,

```
239
286
.
.
.
287
.
.
.
288
289
```

Whenever the first value is around 200, It doesn't seem to work well. I am not able to understand the flaw here.Can anybody please tell me what mistake I am doing here and what needs to be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, if I am understanding your question correctly. I take the first column and look for the number 28 (as a test), at which I point I start calculating the cumulative sum. You will want to change this to 64, unless I have misunderstood.

This method works, but I am sure there are shorter methods to do the same!

```
data = '''               count
0               239
1                47
2                47
3                47
4                47
5                47
6                47
7                47
8                47
9                47
10               47
11               48
12               48
13               48
14               48
15               48
16               48
17               48
18               48
19               48
20               48
21               48
22               48
23               48
24               48
25               48
26               48
27               48
28               49
29               50  '''

cumulative_sum = 0

for line in data.splitlines():
    try:
        tmp = map(int,line.strip().split())
        if tmp[0]>=28:
            cumulative_sum += tmp[1]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```